# Table partitioning vs. splitting the table and execution with multiple connections to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, partitioning, large-data

I have to process a very large table (100MM+ rows) and perform bunch of analytical functions on it, e.g. taking average, sum, percentile, etc.

I was wondering if the best approach is to partition the table and perform my calculations in one stored procedure (with one connection) or if I should split my tables by some column (date for example) to smaller tables and perform my calculations with separate connections to SQL Server?

if the answer is the second one, how can I make sure that all those jobs are finished before I can aggregate all the results to create the final table?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server supports [parallel query plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver16#parallel-query-processing) for SQL queries.  So there's normally no reason to try to run queries over multiple connections to utilize all the server resources.

For large tables, favor storing them as [clustered columnstores](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver16) for optimal compression, column and segment elimination, and fast scanning.